# ARM9 dual core vs ARM8: which perf should highlight the benefits of having dual core in Altera cyclone V SoC

Tags: c++, c, arm, embedded-linux, intel-fpga

I am working with `Altera cyclone V SoC SX`, with `ARM cortex A9 dual core`. I would like to compare it to `ARM8 single core` in order to show which benefits can be explored later in Dev.

1. Is it good enough to compare CPU Load while running a simple application using Loops for examples?
2. Is it possible to enable/disable CPU-Cores while running an application?
3. is it possible to assign to each core (**core_0, core_1**) a specific task?

**Appendice**

```
   Target/Board: Aletra Cyclone V SX, ARM cotex A9 (925Mhz) dual core
   OS: Linux Altera_socfpga 3.7.0
   Host: OpenSuse 42.0 (linux)
```

Comment: Since there arent any ARM8s and I am pretty sure you didnt mean ARM9 but instead ARM cortex-A8 and arm cortex-A9, then they are both ARMv7-A so the same architecture, doesnt necessarily mean same implementation, but I would assume more similar than different.  and likely most of your difference will come from them being part of different chips and systems than the core itself.

Comment: adding linux to it makes it even worse, how are you going to isolate the core differences if that is what you are after?  all of your questions are very specific to the system and software.